# Isolate scope two-way binding doesn't update in time for action to be invoked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular directive which acts as a control which lets the guest pick from multiple choices. When a choice is picked, a variable is assigned in the parent scope and a method is called to indicate that "the guest picked something."

The directive looks like this:

```
module.directive("myThingpicker", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            items: "=",
            item: "=",
            selected: "&"
        },
        templateUrl: "/templates/thing-picker.html",
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.selectItem = function (item) {
                $scope.item = item;
                $scope.selected();
                console.log ("The user picked an item:", item);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

The template is straight forward: `<li>` elements generated using `ng-repeat="x in items"` with an `ng-click="selectItem(x)"` directive.

---

The problem is when `selected` is called, `item` hasn't passed its value up to the parent scope yet. Testing the bound value results in `undefined`. Clicking a second time (and causing a second `selected()` call shows the previous click's value.

In light of this fact, I'd either one of two possible solutions:

#### Pass the value as an argument to `selected`

- If I pass an argument in to `selected`, I get an error *Cannot use 'in' operator to search for...*

#### Force the value of `item` to propagate before `selected()` call.

Comment: Can you paste the code that you use to call `selected` function with arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your `$scope.selected();` to accept a passable argument `item`, that way when the function passed through the `selected` scope executes, it has the data it's looking for.  The callback can then assign the item to a scope variable in the controller if that's what you wish for it to do.

**Directive**

```
module.directive("myThingpicker", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            items: "=",
            selected: "&"
        },
        templateUrl: "/templates/thing-picker.html",
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.selectItem = function (item) {
                $scope.selected(item);
                console.log ("The user picked an item:", item);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
module.directive("fooController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = []; //example of your items
    $scope.selectCallback = function(item) {
        // your code goes here

    };
});
```

**Markup**

```
<my-thingpicker items="model" selected="selectCallback"></my-thingpicker>
```

Comment: This still isn't working; the `$scope.selected(...)` is producing the *Cannot use 'in' operator* error. I made [a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/MHzJNr63) which attempts to implement your solution to no avail. **edit**: `$scope.selected()` returns `selectedCallback`, so I actually need `$scope.selected()(item)`. If you update your answer I'll give you credit.